# AngularJs Validation CSS error

Tags: html, css, angularjs, validation, ng-class

I have a below code which generates 3 text box. Now the problem is when I click on one of the text box, all the 3 text box gets focused, even though they have different values of name and label.

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-ng-repeat="dohPolicy in [1,2,3]">

    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:0px; margin-right:1%;">
        <p style="font-size:11px;">P no {{dohPolicy}} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6"  
            data-ng-class='{ "has-focus": dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus,
                             "has-success": dohForm.dohPolicy.$valid,
                             "has-error": dohForm.dohPolicy.$invalid && (dohForm.$submitted || dohForm.dohPolicy.$touched),
                             "is-empty": !dohForm.dohPolicy.$viewValue }' 
                             style="right: 150px; bottom: 40px; padding: 0;  width:20%;">
        <label for="dohPolicy"></label>
        <input type="text" name="dohPolicy"
                    data-ng-model="dohPolicy" required readonly
                    data-ng-blur='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=false'
                    data-ng-focus='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=true'>
        <p data-ng-show="dohForm.dohPolicy.$error.required && (dohForm.dohPolicy.$touched || submitted)"
                class="error-block">
           P Number(s)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even though I tried using string arrays as well but not able to solve the issue.
I want when I click on particular text box only that text box should get focus and highlighted.

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a code snippet in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="dohPolicy"
                                data-ng-model="dohPolicy" required readonly
                                data-ng-blur='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=false'
                                data-ng-focus='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=true' 
                                >
```

Here ,all input text generated dynamically,`share the same model` **dohPolicy**.

So,they `all get dirty at the same time and emit the blur & focus event`.

You need to add  the unique name of model

Answer (score 0):

As @Riyaj suggested all the input control share the same model & **same name**, so all get dirty at the same time

Name for control must be unique within a form.

You have to give different name for each input control.

```
<form role="form" novalidate name="vm.form">
  <div class="col-md-12" data-ng-repeat="dohPolicy in [1,2,3]">
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:0px; margin-right:1%;">
          <p style="font-size:11px;">P no {{dohPolicy}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6"  
      data-ng-class='{ "has-focus": dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].hasFocus,
              "has-success": dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].$valid,
              "has-error": dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].$invalid && (dohForm.$submitted || dohForm.dohPolicy.$touched),
              "is-empty": !dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].$viewValue }' 
              style="right: 150px; bottom: 40px; padding: 0;  width:20%;">
          <label for="dohPolicy">
          </label>
      <input
          type="text" name="dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}]"
          data-ng-model="dohPolicy" required
          data-ng-blur='dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].hasFocus=false'
          data-ng-focus='dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].hasFocus=true' 
          class="form-control"
          >
          <p
          data-ng-show="dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].$error.required && (dohForm.dohPolicy[{{dohPolicy}}].$touched || submitted)"
          class="error-block">P Number(s)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Use $index in your name attribute and validate dynamically

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-ng-repeat="dohPolicy in [1,2,3]">

    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:0px; margin-right:1%;">
        <p style="font-size:11px;">P no {{dohPolicy}} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6"  
    data-ng-class='{ "has-focus": dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus,
        "has-success": dohForm.dohPolicy.$valid,
        "has-error": dohForm.dohPolicy.$invalid && (dohForm.$submitted || dohForm.dohPolicy.$touched),
        "is-empty": !dohForm.dohPolicy.$viewValue }' 
        style="right: 150px; bottom: 40px; padding: 0;  width:20%;">
        <label for="dohPolicy">
        </label>
    <input
        type="text" name="dohPolicy_{{$index}}"
        data-ng-model="dohPolicy" required readonly
        data-ng-blur='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=false'
        data-ng-focus='dohForm.dohPolicy.hasFocus=true' 
        >
        <p
        data-ng-show="dohForm['dohPolicy_' + $index].$error.required && (dohForm.dohPolicy.$touched || submitted)"
        class="error-block">P Number(s)</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried above solution, still not working, Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error

Comment: I created a plunker. please check https://plnkr.co/edit/hPTwxyjzLbGNpmd8VI4y?p=preview